VMware Workstation Player 17 to 16: To use Unity mode
I have downgraded VMware Workstation Player from version 17 to version 16 as there is no Unity mode in version 17.
Now, when I start the virtual machine, I get the below error:
Error while powering on: Failed to start the virtual machine.

I have tried many methods including restart, run as admin and all the methods found here

Did you upgrade the VM to only support the newer version? What do the logs say?

You need to examine (or post) the UI log (its location should be shown in the About dialog) and the VMX log (the vmware.log file in the VM's directory).
